# How To Export exe files in Visual Studio With All Used Files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exe

So I have been working on a few projects using audio and images from files in Visual Studio C++. As of now they are just test projects, but I am going to be moving now towards making 2D games for fun using SFML and a few different audio libraries. The problem is this, I want to give out my games to others so they can play and test them, and I may try to develop some sort of Multiplayer for some, thus increasing my desire to give it out to others, however I do not know how I can give them the games with all the files included. I used to just be able to grab the exe files out of the debug or release folder, but these projects have files they rely on.

So here is my question, is it possible to export an exe file that contains all the other files (wav's, jpg's etc.)? If this question sounds overwhelmingly stupid then tell me, because I have very little idea of what an exe is, and whether it can hold those files (I am used to java, where u can simply export something into a runnable jar and because it is an archive, with all of the resources prepackaged in there, I don't know if an exe shares these traits). If this is not possible, or there are better alternatives, what are they? I have seen things and know how to load sounds from arrays of data, would that be a better solution? Or are there other options? On top of that, in the debug and release folder there are several DLL files which I need to run the project, is there a way to compress these into the exe or will those have to be in the same folder as the exe no matter what?

The real question here is what is the best way to export an exe file of my project so that I can utilize all of my sound and image resources as well as the dll's into an easy to distribute copy? Thank you in advance to any advice.

Comment: Please edit your question so that it's in actually readable paragraphs; as it is now, it's just one big jumble of letters. Carriage returns between paragraphs work just fine in the question editor. :)

Comment: Add the files to an archive (rar, zip), problem solved.

Comment: I have not done this myself so I cannot answer your specific questions but have you looked into InstallShield or pages such as: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235285.aspx    You are simply needing to deploy or distribute your c++ application which is a common task.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zebw5zk9.aspx

Comment: @thedaian If you are going to provide an answer to my question, please give a detailed explanation and post it as an answer. Just saying "put them in a rar" does not explain what I actually need to do whatsoever. How do I access these files? Where do I put the rar? Etc. Etc. If you are going to answer a question, actually answer it in the answer section, with a real, concise response.

Comment: @MattCofer This only explains it with MFC projects, and I do not know much about them, and my project isnt one for that matter.

Comment: @user1032369: I'd suggest, if you want to have people help you here *for free*, you not criticize the efforts people make to help you. :) It doesn't encourage others to do so.

Comment: @KenWhite I have not critisized the efforts people have given me, one person's response cant even be called an effort, he just wrote half a sentence which explained nothing to me. The second person who responded gave some actual advice, but I dont think it applied to my project, so I asked if there was a way it could. How am I criticizing the efforts people make to help me?

Comment: Your comment about the person who wrote the single line was somewhat rude. If you didn't like it, ignore it; it's a comment, not an answer. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) if you haven't already, particularly the part about how to behave towards others. :)

Comment: @KenWhite I was in no way trying to be rude, he seemed like someone who had an explanation, so I told him if he is going to respond, please give a full response so I can use it. I have read the FAQ and in no way was I trying to spite him, I simply wanted to know more information. I didnt not like it, I simply needed to know more information for my problem to be solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to *export an exe* that contains your exe and multiple other files. You can use an installer (such as [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), which is free), or bundle the extra files into a resource and load them from resource at runtime. (The first has the benefit of being able to ask the user where to install, create shortcuts and folders, Start Menu items, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

There's two easy ways to make a file that you can easily give to people to test and/or play your game.

1. The first option is **using an installer**, as mentioned in Ken White's answer. It's a good method for "final" releases, but it adds an extra step if you just want to send a copy of your game to someone to test it.
2. The second method is put all your files into a single **.zip file** (or .rar, or .tar.bz).  Basically, this is a lot like Java's .jar file, with all the dlls, image files, and sound files into a single file.  Recent versions of Windows have the ability to create zip files built in, so the best way to do it is just zip up the Debug or Release version with all the files, and unzip to an empty folder somewhere, and test the game. Doing that will let you make sure you got all the files you need.  This way, you can easily send your game to someone, they can simply unzip it to a folder somewhere, and play, no messing about with installers.
3. The bonus third option is **sticking the files into a resource** and loading them at runtime, or similar things (it's possible to get really fancy and combine all the files into a single EXE, but it's not exactly easy, and not really advisable).

Comment: The problem with doing the single compressed file is that eventually you need to do an installer anyway, and you have another cycle of testing. Starting with a proper installer lets you test that (and the *uninstaller* functionality) as part of development, and isn't really a big deal once you do the initial configuration. :)